# crystal reports eclipse ms access

Tags: java, eclipse, ms-access, crystal-reports, driver

Does anyone know of any generic jdbc driver to use with eclipse crystal reports because I cant find any that work out. It works 100% in visual studio i.e ms access and crystal reports.

Answer (score 1):

It's typical in JDBC development to get the driver for your database (which is very similar to what is required for ODBC and OLE DB; Microsoft is kind enough to provide you with a driver for their databases in the OS).

Assuming you are trying to connect to Access on a Windows machine, you should be able to leverage the [JDBC-ODBC bridge](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/bridge.doc.html). [This site](http://www.herongyang.com/jdbc/JDBC-ODBC-MS-Access.html) links to some tutorials on getting started (setting up a DSN and connecting via `jdbc:odbc:MyDSN`. Alternatively, if you can afford it, there are some [commercial products](http://www.hxtt.com/access.html) that support connectivity to Access using pure JDBC.